# qt rcc (resource compiler) is non-deterministic - how to make it deterministic

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a command in my makefile that uses the [Qt resource compiler](http://qt.apidoc.info/5.2.0/qtcore/resources.html). 
This utility produces a static array for each image file passed to it.
Unfortunately, `rcc.exe` is non-deterministic: the order of these arrays inside the generated `.cpp` file is different for each invocation.

I ran it three times:

```
>C:\rcc.exe -name lookupmodels lookupmodels.qrc -o .qrc/qrc_lookupmodels-1.cpp

>C:\rcc.exe -name lookupmodels lookupmodels.qrc -o .qrc/qrc_lookupmodels-2.cpp

>C:\rcc.exe -name lookupmodels lookupmodels.qrc -o .qrc/qrc_lookupmodels-3.cpp
```

The `.qrc` file is:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>datapool_pdal1.csv</file>
        <file>events_Ic.csv</file>
        <file>events_Evt.csv</file>
        <file>events_Other.csv</file>
        <file>key_events.csv</file>
        <file>loglevel_DPvalues.csv</file>
        <file>loglevel_Evtvalues.csv</file>
        <file>log_freqDP.csv</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Being arrays of `static const unsigned char`, the `.cpp` files are huge so I won't show them here but the basic problem is that the order of these arrays, which represent images, changes from one invocation to the next.

**ISSUE**

To compare build to build - especially since I'm switching build systems - I need to be able to **compare artifacts.**

I would like them to not change so that I can compare artifact output from build to build to see if something has changed or not.

This is the ONLY object file that is giving me this issue.

Comment: Clearly, you should not rely on the order of the resources then. The resources are accessed by names / paths (as defined in .qrc), not by their order in the .cpp files.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the order of the resource arrays affects the object file which affects my final executable. How else am I supposed to compare executables between builds?

Comment: I see, I missed the last bit of the question. But you can't realistically expect your binaries to match bit-for-bit anyway. At least mine never do, they have stuff like random IDs and date / time.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe is there a "checksum"-type thing that doesn't rely on order of compiled arrays?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I'll **bold** it. My bad

Comment: I doubt. But I think binary comparison is a poor way to solve whatever task it is you're solving there. ESPECIALLY since you're switching build systems which may well produce non-essential object file differences. For instance, if this is for testing, then you'd be much better off writing an actual test and a script that invokes it.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe the build system doesn't change the compiler nor options invoked.

Comment: @MatteoItalia good point. I'll try different versions.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Maybe there is some way. But there's no serious reason it **should** be determenistic. It's the executable code that matters. The code should stay the same. But the object file does not contain just the code, as you already learned, and it musn't necessarily have the same CRC.

Comment: @MatteoItalia my build engineers won't accept the new system unless we get binary compatibility between the two. And there's no reason why we shouldn't, right? Same compiler, build options, still on Windows.

Comment: Equal CRC is a sufficient, but not necessary criterion for binary compatibility.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yeah but it's just this ONE object file. If there were a timestamp embedded in every object file, I'd agree.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I strongly disagree. In a build system (and possibly in any software system) everything should be deterministic, unless there's a strong reason (performance, security, ...) for it not to be. Having a resource compiler generate different outputs for the exact same input is just being mean (and in fact its just an accidental byproduct of using QHash, which at some time, in unrelated changes, gained seed randomization). Fortunately, hash randomization was [disabled](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/85806/) on later versions in "bootstrapped tools".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably it's accidental; internally, rcc uses a `QHash` somewhere, which uses a random seed in its hash function:

http://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/HsoMhGOu/qt-resource-compiler-why-does-it-randomize-the-order-of-items

> It's due to the hash randomisation. This was done to avoid DoS attacks that
>   can be performed by tweaking data to ensure it always falls into the same
>   hash bucket.

To make the hash seed nonrandom (and thus make rcc deterministic) set the environment variable `QT_HASH_SEED` to some fixed numeric value before invoking rcc.

> This randomization of QHash is enabled by default. Even though programs should never depend on a particular QHash ordering, there may be situations where you temporarily need deterministic behavior, for example for debugging or regression testing. To disable the randomization, define the environment variable QT_HASH_SEED. The contents of that variable, interpreted as a decimal value, will be used as the seed for qHash(). Alternatively, you can call the qSetGlobalQHashSeed() function.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#algorithmic-complexity-attacks

---

Anyhow, a patch about this problem [has been merged](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/85806/) (more in general, it should fix similar problems even in uic and moc), so recent versions of Qt shouldn't be affected.

Comment: awesome but I really want to know: how did you find this info? Just googling "QT randomize"?

Comment: The mailing list link was the third Google hit for "qt rcc reproducible build"; there I found a mention of "QT_HASH_SEED", which then I searched and found immediately in the documentation of `QHash`. Glad that helped. =)

Comment: Using `pyside6-rcc` specifically, I still see this indeterminacy problem, even with `QT_HASH_SEED` set to `"0"` (which I understand shouldn't even be needed anymore). Based on some experimentation, the varying bytes are clearly related to the timestamps on the resource files.

Comment: What version? I see a reproducibility fix in 6.4.0 https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/5d8f6beb4640d64a262fa918b47e0073ea39fbda

Answer (score 0):

With the `QT_HASH_SEED` problem referenced in [Matteo Italias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926731/805737) already [fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86675) in recent versions of Qt, there still remains a source of variance (at least with some `rcc` tools). Specifically, the modification timestamps of the resource files themselves are embedded within the output (for some reason). Since a fresh repo clone has fresh timestamps, this can break determinacy in CI/CD systems.

The solution is to set all of the resource file timestamps to a consistent value before running your `rcc` tool. To illustrate with a simple bash example (this is with PySide6's `rcc` tool and GNU/Linux `touch` - adapt to your situation):

```
while read -r fn; do
    touch -t 202201010000.00 "${fn}"
done < <(pyside6-rcc --list path/to/resources.qrc)
pyside6-rcc path/to/resources.qrc -o path/to/output.py # Now consistent
```